# loop through a script when a sheet name begins with X google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

Generally, when you create one or more sheets in a google sheets document, these are called by default "Sheet 1", "Sheet 2", "Sheet 3" ...

I am trying that when one or more new sheets are created manually, the script is activated automatically and detects which sheets start with the name "Sheet".

On sheets that have a name beginning with "Sheet", the script will apply the styles.

I have created a code in google apps script but the problem is that for some reason my code doesn't seem to work ...

This is my code:

```
function newSheet(){
  
  var libro = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var numeroDeHojas = libro.getNumSheets();
 
  for (var i = 0; i < numeroDeHojas; i++) {

    var hojass = libro.getSheets()[i];
    var nombreHoja = hojass.getName();
    Logger.log(hojass);
    Logger.log(nombreHoja);

    if ( nombreHoja == nombreHoja.toString().indexOf('Hoja') ){
     
      hojass.setHiddenGridlines(true); // Ocultar las lineas de cuadricula
      hojass.setColumnWidth(1, 50);  //Modificar tamaño de columna A de las hojas a 50
      hojass.getRange(1, 1, hojass.getMaxRows(), hojass.getMaxColumns()).activate();  //Seleccionar toda las celdas de la hoja
      hojass.getActiveRangeList().setVerticalAlignment('middle').setFontFamily('Open Sans');  //Dar alineación vertical en el medio y fuente Open Sans
      hojass.getRange('A1').activate();   //Quitar la seleccion de todas las celdas de la hoja y activar solo la celda A1
    
    }
  }
}
```

Would someone be so kind to help me? Any help is well appreciated.

Thank you very much

Comment: Is your problem that the function doesn't work or that it's not automatically executed when a new sheet is created? Does it work when you execute it manually?

Comment: The problem is the function, which does not work. When I run it in the editor I get the sheets and sheet names. But from there, it doesn't do anything else.  @DmitryKostyuk

Comment: OK, I've just posted my answer, you can go to the 2nd point directly and it will work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## I got your function to work :)

There are two things you need to pay attention to.

### Setting the trigger

I don't know if you've done that and if the trigger is working, but you need an `onChange` trigger like so (just execute it from the IDE directly once):

```js
const setTrigger = () => {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("newSheet")
    .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
    .onChange()
    .create();
}
```

Your `newSheet()` function will then receive an event as its parameter. For performance reasons, you might want to refactor the beginning of your function like so:

```js
function newSheet(e){ // e is the event passed by the trigger
  if(e.changeType !== "INSERT_GRID") return; // don't run if the function was triggered by something which is not a creation of a new sheet
  // rest of the code as is
}
```

This makes sure you don't uselessly run the function but only when a new sheet is created.

### Your `if` statement is wrong

This is the proper way to test the value returned by `indexOf`:

```js
if (-1 !== nombreHoja.indexOf('Hoja')) {
  // the actual code is fine
}
```

There are also some other improvements that can be made to your code, but it does work the way it is, so you should be fine ;)

Comment: This works perfect! I had thought about creating a timed trigger for this, however, your trigger is so much better! And with the changeType this will prevent it from executing unnecessarily. Just great! Oh my, I had thought about -1 but it was not clear in my head. Her response is great. I have learned new things very clearly. I thank you very much for your very definite and explanatory answer, as well as your time. Thank you very much @DmitryKostyuk